# How to generate xml tags dynamically from Rails DB using Nokogiri XML Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri, xml-builder

I want to build xml from rails application. I wanted to generate tags from rails application database.

For example: I have a database table called cars and it have variable brand and it has values.

So I want to generate xml like this

```
<dodge> </dodge>
```

I tried by doing so

```
xml.cars.brand do 

end
```

### But I'm getting NoMethodError

Comment: Please show the full error. What is `cars`? What is `cars.brand`? Is there a car without a brand? And what is `xml`?

Comment: Cars is the table name, Brand is the column name and I wanted to generate this xml using xml nokogiri builder and I've edited my question, Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You have not provided much to go on and if your comment is accurate than your answer is not. `Cars.brand` will call the `brand` method on the class instance `Cars` but in your comment you stated that `brand` is an attribute method of an instance of `Car` not the class itself. Therefor the answer posted is likely to raise `NoMethodError` for `Cars`, which btw is not the correct model name under rails convention as model names are singular

Comment: Ya that was the typo, Thanks for correcting me, Edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create variable in the controller like this

```
brand = Car.find(id).brand
```

and then generate xml like below

```
xml.tag!(brand) do

end
```